# Spring - How to handle an empty value in bean

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc

I would like to ask how to handle a case if I get an empty value in bean.

the scenario is that I have a spring that load a property file and store the new property (that I just added) to `myProp` value:

```
<bean id="ConfigurationUtility" class="configuration.ConfigurationUtility">
    <property name="UntilTimeInQuote" value="myProp"/>
</bean>
```

When the property set to `true` or `false` everything works fine and as expected. However, I want to handle a case that the property does not exist in the property file at all, meaning it gets `null`.

How to catch that state and handle in the code?

Comment: How exactly would you want to handle such errors?

Answer (score 0):

You can define your property as a boolean object and process the value in the setter. In this way you can manage the value at the moment when spring set the value.

```
public class MyBean{
private Boolean untilTimeInQuote;
public setUntilTimeInQuote(Boolean value){
if(value == null){
//do something.
}else{
// do something else.
}
}
}
```

Another option is to use a bean post processor action, it's fired after the bean creation and after the properties are set.

```
public class MyBean{
private Boolean untilTimeInQuote;

@PostConstruct
public void init(){
if(untilTimeInQuote == null){
//do something.
}else{
// do something else.
}
}

public setUntilTimeInQuote(Boolean value){
this.untilTimeInQuote = value
}
}
}
```

you can see more here
https://www.mkyong.com/spring/spring-postconstruct-and-predestroy-example/

Answer (score 0):

If you're using `@Value` to inject the properties into your classes, then you can supply a default to use if the properties file doesn't specify one:

```
public class MyClass {
    @Value("${myProperty:false}")
    private boolean myProperty;

    @Value("${serverUrl:localhost}")
    private String serverUrl;
}
```

Now

- `myProperty` will be `false` if nothing supplied for it.
- `serverUrl` will be `localhost` if nothing supplied for it.

I like this way: no "handling" necessary - just a default value to use instead.

Answer (score 0):

There's a whole chapter on [bean validation](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/html/validation.html).

In particular, if you declare a `BeanValidationPostProcessor`, then you can use annotations on your classes to define constraints:

```
@Data
public class ConfigurationUtility {

    private boolean defaultsToFalseIfMissing = false;

    @NotNull
    private Boolean errorsIfMissing;

    @NotBlank
    private String mustBeSetToSomethingPrintable;

}
```

Annotation documentation:

- [`lombok.Data`](https://projectlombok.org/features/Data.html) (used to simplify the example code)
- [`javax.validation.constraints.NotNull`](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/validation/constraints/NotNull.html)
- [`org.hibernate.validator.constraints.NotBlank`](https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/stable/validator/api/org/hibernate/validator/constraints/NotBlank.html)